# How to add a Tertiary job indicator in the Job Screen for a Job in PeopleSoft

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, peoplesoft

Hi PeopleSoft Gurus:  I need help adding more job indicators in PeopleSoft to be used to interface with in external system.  Does anyone know how to add to the drop-down as noted here: http://take.ms/edDHX.

Right now, the options are:

- N=Not Applicable
- P=Primary Job
- S=Secondary Job
- T=Tertiary Job **<---
  Currently not listed, would like to add this**

I'm thinking it's managed in the Set Up HRMS, Foundation Tables, Job Attributes section but I can't seem to find it.  We can't use Employee Record Number because our unique business rules don't always line up with a correct sequence.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to add a new translate value to the JOB_INDICATOR field.

You can do this under the following navigation:
Main Menu > PeopleTools > Utilities > Administration > Translate Values
and search there for the field JOB_INDICATOR.

[Image of the JOB_INDICATOR translate value setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8I7O.png)

Comment: Perfect!  That did it!  Thank you Robin.